# Is it possible to revert to previous version of code in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I made some changes to a project in VsCode, and want to revert to a previous version. I didn't do any commits. Is this possible?

Comment: Try this: Ctrl+Z, other then that, or some third party component this is not possible with VSCode as far as I know.

Comment: Use a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control_system). (Many of them integrate with VsCode)

Comment: @Bergi I'm using Git, but didn't commit anything before making the changes I want to undo. Anything I can do?

Comment: Then probably no. Commit early, commit often - although even `git add` stores a snapshot every time, so if you used any git commands you might be able to find the state in the reflog.

Comment: choose an OS with file versioning (on save) like VMS. Or use an incremental backup tool, to save a snapshot every X min and keep versions of every Y hours, every Z days. Otherwise make a snapshot when you start something new, in git do it in a new branch.